# Path Finding in 3d environment in Java

Tags: language-agnostic

I understand that there are a couple of links about path finding in 2d.Is there any java example that shows how to implement path findings in 3d environment.

I have already seen lot of code and explanations about this.but none of them will really help.How to implement this in 3d enviorment

Comment: Why has the code you have already seen not helped?

Comment: Thanks.I do not have experience in using in 3d environment.That is why I asked for sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean 3d pathfinding as 2d pathfinding in 3d space. For example, you have a 3d scene and something needs to find its way around the walls and rooms. If this is the case you can just make some system to keep track of all your walls (say... BSP tree?) and then implement a common pathfinding algorithm such as A*.